# When we dont mention class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I'm new python learner. As we see in object oriented languages like Java where `class` is blue of any creation in language.

Want to know, In python I've seen code where classes are not mentioned.

```
import datetime                    #Deltatime library, to get Real Date information.
import os                          #OS (Operating system) , To provide cross-platform compatibility
 
list_foods = &#91;]                    #Variable List of foods, names + prices.
list_drinks = &#91;]                   #Variable List of drinks, names + prices.
list_services = &#91;]                 #Variable List of other services, names + prices.
 
list_item_price = &#91;0] * 100        #Variable List of item prices. Index: 0-39 for foods, index: 40-79 for drinks,
                                   #Index: 80-99 for other services.
var_discount_1 = 200                      #First discount starts.
var_discount_2 = 1000                     #Second discount starts.
var_discount_3 = 5000                     #Third discount starts.
var_discount_1_rate = 0.05                #First discount rate.
var_discount_2_rate = 0.10                #Second discount rate.
var_discount_3_rate = 0.15                #Third discount rate.
 
 
navigator_symbol = "/" # This will make the program runnable on any unix based enviroument because it has differnet file system
if os.name == "nt":
    navigator_symbol = "\\" # This will make the program runnable on Windows
 
 
def def_default():
    global list_drinks, list_foods, list_services, list_item_order, list_item_price    
    list_item_order = &#91;0] * 100                    #Create a list, length 100. Max index number is 99.
def_default()                                      #Index: 0-39 for foods, index: 40-79 for drinks,
                                                   #Index: 80-99 for other services. Global variables.
```

As we can see in above sample code, there are some variables and functions too. So these falls under which class ? If don't mention class, does python automatically create class with same name from which AnyName.py is created in IDE ?

Can anyone help me to understand, how it works in python ?

Comment: There is no need for these things to live in a class – neither in Python nor in many other languages. Requiring everything to be in a class is the exceptional behaviour, not the other way around.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, so in above example, if I want to call any of the defined variables or functions then under what reference they should be called ?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, var_discount_1or navigator_symbol or def_default() entities are part of what ?

Comment: Your code already shows how `def_default()` is both defined as a function *and* called.

Answer (score 2):

Python is a multi-paradigm language and does not enforce `class`es as its fundamental building block. A `.py` file corresponds to a module declaration* and all top-level assignments create module attributes, which reside in the modules `__dict__` aka its `globals`.

```py
# my_module.py
answer = 42

def ask(question):
    return answer
```

```py
import my_module         # load my_module.py as a module

print(my_module.answer)  # top-level assignments create module attributes
print(my_module.ask)     # top-level definitions create module attributes
print(my_module.ask("What is the meaning of modules?"))
```

While Python does not require everything to be *in* a class, it requires everything to *be of* a type. All `.py` modules* are automatically created as instances of the builtin [ModuleType](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType), which supports arbitrary attributes of any name and type.

---

* Unless using some very uncommon meta-programming.

Comment: so you mean types.ModuleType acts as a "java.lang.Class<T>" in java ?